# Wilson loop shapes and glueball operators

Tags: quantum-field-theory, wilson-loop, lattice-gauge-theory

In the AdS/QCD correspondence, glueballs operators are given, for example, by $\text{Tr}[F_{\mu \nu}F^{\mu \nu}]$ for $0^{++}$ or $\text{Tr}[F_{\mu \nu}\widetilde{F}^{\mu \nu}]$ for $0^{-+}$. However, in [this link](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-lat/9901004)<sup>1</sup>, figure 1, it is stated that glueball operators are made from linear combinations of these Wilson loops. My question is: Is there a link between these two approaches? Or phrased differently: Can we deduce glueball operators in AdS/QCD from those Wilson loops?

---

1. C. J. Morningstar and M. Peardon, "Glueball spectrum from an anisotropic lattice study", [*Phys. Rev. D* **60**, 034509 (1999)](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.60.034509), arXiv:hep-lat/9901004.

Comment: I'm not sure where you see a difference between the two approaches. E.g. one might also say that in the standard model you have operators $e$, $\mu$, $\tau$ for the three leptons, or one might say that "lepton states are created by linear combinations of $e$, $\mu$, $\tau$". It's just a different emphasis of talking about specific particles vs. a group of particles, but where is the difference?

Comment: My confusion comes from the fact that Wilson loops are expressed as $W_p = \text{Tr}\left[\mathcal{P}\,e^{i \int_{\partial p} A}\right]$, while in AdS/QCD they are expressed as $ \text{Tr}[F_{\mu \nu}F^{\mu \nu}]$ etc.. Especially I don't know how to recover the lasts from the Wilson loops on differents contours.

Comment: For future reference: It would have helped me to understand the question better if you had said a bit more explicitly that the problem is the connection between $\mathrm{tr}(F^2)$ and the Wilson loops, not the "linear combination" part. Also, please consider mentioning author and title of papers you refer to in the post itself to guard against [link rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "glueball operators are Wilson loops" is the non-perturbative viewpoint amenable to lattice computations, while the "glueball operators are quadratics in the field strength" is the perturbative viewpoint.

The connection between them comes from reasoning like in [*"Interaction of Wilson loops in confining vacuum"*](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0204285v1) by Shevchenko and Simonov, where they show that in the limit of large Wilson loops - compared to the gluon correlation length - and to lowest order in perturbation theory (i.e. the coupling constant $g$), we have schematically that
$$ \langle W \rangle \propto \langle \mathrm{tr}(F^2)\rangle,$$
where $W$ is a Wilson loop and $F^2 = F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}$ (this is their eqs. (25) + (26)).

Comment: So, if I want to calculate the two-point function for the $0^{-+}$, I ``just'' have to calculate the correlation function between to Wilson loops, given a certain type of contour?

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux Yes, I think so. (I don't really know a lot about glueballs in particular, so if you have another specific question about them, feel free to ask it as a new question on the site!)

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux Yes; that's mostly correct. The situation in 2 spatial dimensions is well summarized in https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-lat/9804008.pdf by Michael J. Teper. In particular see page 9 and page 10 where they lay out how to construct glueball operators. It's not just a correlation function between two wilson loops; it's the correlation function between the linear combinations of the traces of parity transformed/rotated wilson loops. It's the real part of the trace for C (Charge Parity)+ glueballs, the imaginary part for C- glueballs.